# Groups of homotopy spheres II?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Where can I find "Groups of homotopy spheres: II", the sequel to "[Groups of homotopy spheres: I](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kervmiln.pdf)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kervaire and Milnor never published the second part, but *[Lectures on Groups of Homotopy Spheres](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/levsph.pdf)* by J. Levine can be considered as a pseudosequel. In the second paragraph, Levine points out that the notes cover what he imagined would have been in *Groups of Homotopy Spheres: II*.

Answer (score 2):

«Sadly, the promised paper "Groups of Homotopy Spheres: II" never appeared» ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere))

Comment: The next question is probably "What would GoHS II contain if it had appeared?"  Followed by "Where can I find that stuff?"